# highlight next immediate to input value in html table cell with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

1. I am having a table cell with the heading **Current Level**.
2. An input textbox Basic
3. If the user enters any of the figures of the table cell in the input textbox, it would be highlighted.
4. I would like to highlight the immediate next cell value also.

here is what I try to achieve with a working demo.
please help me to achieve this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <style>
        
        .highlight
        {
        color:red;
        background-color:yellow;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
        </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <table width="100%" border="0">
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td>Basic</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb"  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            
                          </table>
                            
                        </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <td><h6>Current Level</h6></td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table id="le10" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                            
                            <tr><td>56100</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>57800</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>59500</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>61300</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>63100</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>65000</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>67000</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>69000</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>71100</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>73200</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>75400</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>77700</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--match and highlight the Current basic textbox value with the level table-->
        <script>
        $(function(){
        console.log('');
        $('#cb').on('input', function() {
          var textboxValue = $('#cb').val();
          if(textboxValue.length>0)
          {
          $('#le10 td').each(function() {
            var filter = textboxValue.toString().toUpperCase();
            if ($(this).html().toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              $(this).addClass('highlight');
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            }
          });
          }
          else
          {
          $('#le10 td').removeClass('highlight');
          }
        });
        });
        </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.highlight2 {
  color: blue;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="">Basic</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb" autocomplete="off" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h6>Current Level</h6>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="le10" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
          <tr>
            <td>56100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>57800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>59500</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>61300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>63100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>65000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>67000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>69000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>71100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>73200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>75400</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>77700</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('#cb').on('change keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $('table tr td').filter(function() {
        if($(this).text() == search){
          $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
          $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
        }else{
          $(this).parent('tr').removeClass('highlight');
          $(this).parent('tr').closest('tr').next().removeClass('highlight2');
        }
    })
  });
});
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSE6Z.png)

Reference:

- https://api.jquery.com/parent/
- https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-selector

Comment: The answer was helpful and I added one more table cell with values.  I am unable to extend the search to that table as well.  How can I extend the search of next closest, I mean the third search to be happened in the new table cell value and the latest value to be shown in the next basic textbox value.

Comment: <td>
    <table  id="le11" class="table table-responsive table-striped">
     
     <tr><td>67700</td></tr>
     <tr><td>69700</td></tr>
     <tr><td>71800</td></tr>
     <tr><td>74000</td></tr>
     <tr><td>76200</td></tr>
     <tr><td>78500</td></tr>
     <tr><td>80900</td></tr>
     <tr><td>83300</td></tr>
     <tr><td>85800</td></tr>
     <tr><td>88400</td></tr>
     <tr><td>91100</td></tr>
     <tr><td>93800</td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  
   <td>
    Next Basic</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb"  />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>

Comment: @shankar_sb So, not sure if I got you right, If you want is another table with same feature in the same page, all you have to do a little change only in `js code`. Change will be in this `$('table tr td').filter(function() {` line. Just add table id like `$('table#le11 tr td').filter(function() {` this.

Comment: the above i tried but not working.  say for example there is another table id le11 and the cell values are <tr><td>67700</td></tr> <tr><td>69700</td> ... after hightlighting the two values in table id le10 i.e. 65000 and 67000, the next value to be highlighted in table id le11 as 67700.  I replaced the above line of code as $('table#le10 tr td, table#le11 tr td').filter(function() { and $(this).parent('table#le11 tr').closest('table#le11 tr').next().addClass('highlight2'); but not working

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter if the styling occurs on a td or tr, you can use this code to achieve it.

```
<script>
    $(function(){ 
        console.log(''); 
        $('#cb').on('input', function() { 
            var textboxValue = $('#cb').val(); 
            if(textboxValue.length>0) { 
                $('#le10 td').each(function() { 
                    var filter = textboxValue.toString().toUpperCase(); 
                    if ($(this).html().toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
                        $(this).addClass('highlight');
                        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').addClass('highlight'); 
                    } else { 
                        $(this).removeClass('highlight'); 
                        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').removeClass('highlight'); 
                    } 
                }); 
            } else { 
                $('#le10 td').removeClass('highlight'); 
                $('#le10 tr').removeClass('highlight'); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
 </script>
```